# Javascript: reduce array of objects in array of properties object

Tags: javascript

I want reduce an array of object, eg.:

```
const users = [
    {id: 1, username: 'foo'}, 
    {id: 2, username: 'bar'}, 
    {id: 3, username: 'baz'}
];
```

to an array of id, eg.:

```
users.reduce( magicReducer ); // output: [1,2,3]
```

is possible?

Comment: Try this `users.map(({id}) => id);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ?

Comment: `users.reduce((acc, {id}) => acc.concat(id), [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `reduce` for the required magic, you can simply use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this like:

```js
const users = [{id: 1, username: 'foo'}, {id: 2, username: 'bar'}, {id: 3, username: 'baz'}];
const res = users.map(({id}) => id);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

This should solve the problem for you !

```js
const users = [{id: 1, username: 'foo'}, {id: 2, username: 'bar'}, {id: 3, username: 'baz'}];

console.log(users.map(user => user.id))
```

Comment: Please vote to close questions that have been asked thousands of times

Comment: @adiga , I dont think I have that privilege yet.

Comment: You get access to [flag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as duplicates at 15 reps.

Comment: Sure will make sure do the same next time! THank for the information

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
const users = [
    {id: 1, username: 'foo'}, 
    {id: 2, username: 'bar'}, 
    {id: 3, username: 'baz'}
];

ids=users.map(x=>x.id)
console.log(ids)
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates.